# Cannot start Emacs daemon server after forced reboot

Tags: server

I was running Emacs in daemon server mode when my computer was force rebooted. After reboot was complete, I could not start the Emacs server again, receiving the error message:

```
Starting Emacs daemon.
Unable to start the daemon.
Another instance of Emacs is running the server, either as daemon or interactively.
```

How do I remedy this?

Comment: `C-h f server-start` says: `To force-start a server, do M-x server-force-delete and then
M-x server-start.`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To prevent multiple daemon sessions with the same name running, Emacs daemon server uses a lock file. Normally when the daemon stops (say by running `kill-emacs`), it deletes this file as part of cleanup, but in the case of a forced PC restart or shutdown (say via power loss) the lock file may remain despite no daemon running. This will prevent a new daemon from starting.

There are a few ways to resolve this.

Solution #1: start up Emacs without a daemon, run `M-x server-force-delete` to delete the lockfile, then start the daemon (say via `M-x server-start`).

Solution #2: delete the lockfile, typically stored under `~/.emacs.d/server/server` or `/run/user/<uid>/server`. (The exact name of the lockfile may differ if you name your sessions.)

Comment: It can also end up in `/run/user/<uid>/server`.